# Arduino offline commands

Tags: arduino-uno

I wanted to know if there is a way for my arduino to keep the last command I sent to it before I disconnected it from my computer. Thanks.

Comment: Huh? I think you need to provide a little more detail as to what you are trying to achieve? What do you mean by the last command? Can you provide an example of your work flow? What command, what does the command cause to happen, and what do you mean "keep the last command" before you disconnect. As your question stands, I think that the answer is to just use an external power supply (e.g. a 9 Volt power supply or a battery) plugged into the barrel power connector on the Arduino before you unplug the it from your computer.

Comment: what does this mean? ... `disconnected it from my computer` ... there is more than one possible meaning

Comment: You mean the last sketch (i.e. program) you uploaded? It's already kept in the Arduino.

Comment: It's even posssible to store something in the Arduino while switching power off and on again, using the EEPROM. (But that's more complicated).

Answer (score 2):

Arduino always store the last sketch you have uploaded. Even if you disconnect your board and then replug it then it follow the same commands that you gave earlier.